# Error when self updating an android application

Tags: android, in-app-update

I have downloaded the apk file that I need successfully. To try if the apk file that I have downloaded is not corrupted and can be installed correctly, I manually click the complete downloaded apk file to update my application and it installs right. Going further, I am trying to install the update automatically. Meaning, as soon as the file is downloaded completely, I want the application to update itself. The application that downloads the file is the same application that will be updated by the updated apk. This should work like the Google In-App update but without the Google Play Store. With the application that downloaded the file is running and by manually tapping the downloaded file, I can still install the update to this application without issues. It's just that, when I try to do this automatically, it gives the error like so:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.google.android.packageinstaller, PID: 15764
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{f4c3105 15764:com.google.android.packageinstaller/u0a18} (pid=15764, uid=10018) that is not exported from uid 10099
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4199)
at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5508)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2239)
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1520)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1133)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:986)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:706)
at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity$StagingAsyncTask.doInBackground(PackageInstallerActivity.java:792)
at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity$StagingAsyncTask.doInBackground(PackageInstallerActivity.java:783)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

This is how I implement the opening and attempt to install the update

```
private void openDownloadedAttachment(final Context context, final long downloadId, Uri uri) {
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
    query.setFilterById(downloadId);
    Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        @SuppressLint("Range")
        int downloadStatus = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        @SuppressLint("Range")
        String downloadLocalUri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
        @SuppressLint("Range")
        String downloadMimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE));
        if ((downloadStatus == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) && downloadLocalUri != null) {
            try {
                downloadLocalUri = "/storage/emulated/0/AATv2.apk";
                openDownloadedAttachment(context, Uri.parse(downloadLocalUri), downloadMimeType);
                Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION );
                File file = new File(downloadLocalUri);
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".provider",
                        file);
                promptInstall.setDataAndType(uri,
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(promptInstall);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

<application>
        .....
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION );
```

You need to call `addFlags()` instead of `setFlags()`. When you call `addFlags()` this adds the flags you specify to the flags that are already set in the `Intent`. When you call `setFlags()` this overwrites the flags that are already set in the `Intent` with the flags you specify.

In your code, the last call to `setFlags()` sets `FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` but the other flags (`FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION, FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`) are cleared.

Comment: I will try this Sir... Give me a moment.

Comment: I tried editing the setFlags to addFlags, I still get the error...

Comment: I also tried 
 promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION );

Comment: You need to change all calls from `setFlags()` to `addFlags()`. Did you do that?

Comment: Thank you Sir. It is woking now. Although I encountered another problem. But, it is for another question.